# Masonry layout with "almost" equal columns using flexbox

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, masonry

I have implemented layout calculation with the help of JS, that calculates each column and fills in each column with elements.
The basic idea is following:

- calculate total height of all elements
- split items into equal columns according to the height of each element (columns count depends on screen width)
- items order does matter

"equal columns" means not exactly equal but approximately.

[JS layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxwLk.png)

I know that flexbox can fill in each column until flexbox reaches height limit for column, then flexbox starts filling in next column...
But I want "equal columns"...

My question is not about [Why is the two p-tags not beside each other when the screen is wide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850524/why-is-the-two-p-tags-not-beside-each-other-when-the-screen-is-wide/20862961#20862961) or [Horizontal masonry layout with flexbox CSS only [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681572/horizontal-masonry-layout-with-flexbox-css-only), maybe something like [How to split a nested navigation into columns with almost equal heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058474/how-to-split-a-nested-navigation-into-columns-with-almost-equal-heights) but without JS and without "column fill in limitation".

Is it possible to implement such behavior with flexbox and without JavaScript?